# Generating Release APK Fails at bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

Tags: node.js, gradle, react-native, gradlew

Every time I try to run: `./gradlew assembleRelease` I get the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'react-native''
```

Here is the output of the stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/rpastorelle/f0a42a87656e5326a186de4e34f691a0

It does work if I use `sudo` to run that command. However, that majorly screws up some permissions and then I get "Could not expand ZIP" errors in Android Studio when building a debug version.

My global npm modules are in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` & I am the user that owns that folder. `react-native-cli` was not installed using `sudo`.

Comment: Have you generate a signing key?

Comment: @KalebPortillo Yes. As stated, I can get it to work using `sudo` ... It just messed up some other things...

Answer (score 7):

My workaround is to run `./gradlew --stop` (which stops the daemon)

Answer (score 0):

If `./gradlew assembleRelease` does't want to generate new `index.android.bundle` file in the assets folder then put the code in `app/build.gradle` mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58458802/3880451 to disable `bundleJsAndAssets`.