# Not able to make release APK React Native Android app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, release

i want to make release for android application in react native so when i generate build i got below error message like

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'node''

see attachment also

[image]

any idea how can i solve this ? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: Can you tell me did you create the project using `react-native init` or `create-react-native init`? as you can easily generate released apk if you created project via `create-react-native init`.

Comment: badarshahzad : I create project from `react-native init`

Answer (score 7):

> After spending 2 days I resolved it, Please follow the below steps:-

**1) Stop Running Gradle**

```
 $ cd RectNatoveProjectName & cd android  (Open your project and go to android folder)  
 $ ./gradlew --stop (Run this command to stop old running Gradle service )
```

**2) Update the android app build gradle**

```
project.ext.react = [
        nodeExecutableAndArgs : ["/usr/local/bin/node"]
];
```

**3) Get Node details**

```
$ which node
```

*> (Result will be like "/usr/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node")*

**4) Link node (very imp step copy the above result in step 3)**

```
- ln -s /usr/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

**5) If Step - 4 return file exist**
- then to go the folder /usr/local/bin/ and delete the "node" file and perform the step -4 again.

**6) If Step - 4 run successfully then this node issue will be resolved.**

Comment: I followed steps 1, 2, and 3 to specify the node location and solve the issue with my node configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below following code in `app/build.gradle` at the end of the file.

```
 afterEvaluate{
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.ext.bundleJsAndAssets.enabled = false
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can have following possible solutions:
1] You need to change the node executable path in your build.gradle(i.e android/app/build.gradle) file as follows:

```
project.ext.react = [
        nodeExecutableAndArgs : ["/usr/local/bin/node"]
];
```

Or
2] You need to close your Android Studio and need to run below command from project root directory:

```
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Or
3] You need to simply run "./gradlew --stop" command and then run "./gradlew assembleRelease" command

Comment: i tried with your above first one solution but i get other error /Volumes/DATA/Projects/ReactNative/RN_CollabaJob/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png
Error:error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..

Comment: When i try second solution in terminal i get -bash: gradlew: command not found

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya, The previous commands shared were for windows OS. At that time I was unaware of OS you are using. BTW for second solution, please use ./gradlew assembleRelease. I have updated the answer. Please check the same.